# Can sales tax in a foreign country be used as credits to offset US taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, sales-tax, foreign-income, tax-credit

Say you are an American citizen living in the UK.

You are required by [draconian] U.S. law to pay full taxes on your income as though you are resident in the U.S. However, there are several treaties and amendments that allow you to minimize your U.S. tax bill.

One of these is Foreign Tax Credits. This allows you to credit the amounts you've paid to the UK government against your U.S. taxes. This applies to some types of income and some types of taxes.

My question is, does it apply to sales tax?

For example, can I claim a credit for all the excess sales tax (i.e. VAT) I've paid while resident in the UK, compared to the much lower sales taxes I would have paid in the U.S.?

Comment: No. "the predominant character of the [foreign] tax must be that of an income tax" https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/what-foreign-taxes-qualify-for-the-foreign-tax-credit

Comment: This. If it was an answer, I'd upvote it.